# Generated proxy class and ClientCredentials(username authentication)

Tags: c#, wcf

While adding reference of webservice through visual studio, the ClientCredentials property of ClientBase abstract class is available. But when the proxy class is generated using wsdl.exe util the ClientCredentials property is not available. What is the problem in the second method? Any help please.